# How to detect digiscan viewing is on?

Tags: hardware, dm-script

Is there a function like "DS_viewingIsOn()" in DM script?
I found a function, DSisAcquisationAcive(), but it is not available before GMS 2.3. Can we sense the digiscan action before GMS 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command was added in GMS 2.2 and just documented from GMS 2.3 onward. Before introducing this command, there was no such scripting capability.

If you are on the GMS 2.x series you should be able to update to the latest GMS 2.x for free.